# Jquery response trimming the values from the server response

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

I am using asp.net to get the server response through JQuery AJAX which returns as JSON format. I have tried using `JQuery.getJSON()` and normal jquery response then convert it to JSON format using `$.parseJSON`.

In both the cases, some times (1 out of 5) the response is not complete what server send so, it shows JSON parsing error. I have tried to change it to simple AJAX call (without JQuery) now it happens rarely (may be 1 out of 20).

My content length varies from few bytes to maximum of 200KB.

My Question is

1. Why JQuery AJAX response is trimming more frequently then normal AJAX.
2. If there is response size limitation, how it works most of the time and some time fails.
3. Is there anything I am missing in my code during call or response headers.

Comment: This is more than likely a server-side issue where the response is firing before it's ready, or it's firing with improperly formatted JSON...

Comment: Use simple AJAX call & open console to see the exact response of the server... before parsing it.

Comment: Yes, I see the console (firebug) and the response is not complete as sent from server

Comment: You haven't mentioned what is generating the JSON server side. For any regularly used solution I know of, if the message is too big, you would never get an incomplete response; you'd get some form of error, or in some cases the server might just terminate the connection.

Comment: May be the server returns partial data some time before complete the process.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue with asp.net response sends before completes the process output. To fix this we need to use

```
Response.BufferOutput = True
Response.Write("Some data")
Response.Flush()
```